# JavaScript boolean variable is true even if nothing is passed

Tags: javascript, variables

I have the following if clause:

```
if(trackingEnabled && tracking) {
  // do something
}
```

Both variables are function parameters. In some cases the `tracking` variable is set as a boolean, in some cases not.

If I lookup the variable's type (in the case that I don't pass a value), then it is a simple Object.

My question is now, why is the tracking variable interpreted as a boolean (value is true) when I don't pass anything to the function?

Comment: You mentioned it is in a function, can you post a code with a function so that we can reproduce?

Comment: If you don't pass anything, the value will be `undefined`. If it's not, then you're passing something.

Comment: *"If I lookup the variable's type (in the case that I don't pass a value), then it is a simple Object."*: If it is an object, then it's true-ish.

Comment: (apart from `null` :P) :D Good point though. `null` is not an object but `typeof` returns `object` for it. But if the OP says the type of the argument is a object and it evaluates to true, then it's probably not `null`.

Comment: If you need to check if `tracking` was passed anything, use `typeof tracking !== "undefined"`, not just checking for truthy `tracking`

Comment: Or check the value of `arguments.length` since you CAN pass an argument whose value is `undefined`

Comment: @HBP That's why it's safer to use `typeof`. I think the point is that the OP wants the second parameter to be "false" for passing `undefined` or passing nothing at all (or maybe passing null), but "true" for everything else. I don't know, there's too much left out to determine what's happening and what needs done.

Comment: @FelixKling I just figured out, that if I don't pass tracking then an jQuery.Event object is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you paste the whole code (method call). I've tried code below in IE9, FF14 and Chrome 23, and code inside if statemenet never gets executed, while typeof b is evaluated to either undefined and object, respectively to method calls.

```
function f(a,b){
 console.log("Type of b is " + typeof b);
 if(a && b){
     console.log(a);
     console.log(typeof a);
     console.log(b);
     console.log(typeof b);
 }
}
f(true);
f(true,null);
```

I see two possible causes

1) You have something passed in function

2) You have some weird Javascript execution environment

Comment: It seems that, if I don't pass a parameter for tracking, then the type is a jQuery.Event (or something). So if NOT NULL == true then the problem is solved. I am no JavaScript expert ;)